# Segmentation Fault C++ array

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a method of a class which increases the size of a dynamic array by twice, copies the data to new double sized array and then deletes the old array.

My function works from size 0 to 8 but after reaching size of 8, it gives a segmentation fault(core dumped). I try to find the reason using valgrind and debugger and tried different options but nothing worked so far.

```
Void Arr::double_capacity(){
    if(array_capacity == 0){
        array_capacity = 1;
        pointer_to_array = new double(array_capacity);
        return;
    }
    if(array_size == array_capacity){
        double* temp = pointer_to_array;
        pointer_to_array = NULL;
        pointer_to_array = new double(array_capacity * 2);
        std::copy(temp, temp + array_size, pointer_to_array);
        delete[] temp;
        temp = NULL;
        array_capacity = array_capacity * 2;
    }

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This is one method, and I count at least two variable names and one class name that are referenced in this code snippet and never defined. There's no way we can reproduce your error with this snippet alone. Are those missing variables instance variables? Are they statics? `extern` variables defined in C? How is the class initialized, and what is the original value of the array? Are we using `new`, `std::vector`, or `malloc`? There are so many details left to the imagination here.

Answer (score 2):

`new double(array_capacity)` creates a single `double` and initializes its value with `array_capacity` converted to `double`. You need to use `[]` brackets to create an array:

```
new double[array_capacity]
```

It would be far easier to use an existing type that takes ownership of the element and provides a move assignment operator, e.g. `std::vector<double>` or `std::unique_ptr<double[]>`.

```
std::unique_ptr<double[]> pointer_to_array;

...

pointer_to_array = std::make_unique<double[]>(array_capacity);

...

std::unique_ptr<double[]> temp = std::make_unique<double[]>(array_capacity * 2);
std::copy_n(pointer_to_array.get(), pointer_to_array.get() + array_capacity, temp.get());
pointer_to_array = std::move(temp);
...
```

(note: no `new[]` and `delete[]` operations are needed to be used directly, if you use `std::unique_ptr<double[]>`)